# Why For loop in java gives different results if we put a space in the print statement and then print the variable

Tags: java

```java
public class Countingtable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write a program to count/increase a number by 2 everytime.
        int number1;
        for (number1 = 2; number1 <= 20; number1++)
            System.out.println("this number is a multiple of 2  " + number1);
    }
}
```

Please note, If I remove the space in the print statement it gives different results?
any clue will help and appreciated

```
System.out.println("this number is a multiple of 2" + number1);
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please show your output.

Comment: Why would you expect the same result with different strings?

Comment: well, the removed spaces will (*obviously*) not be printed - so instead of `... of 2   2` , it will print `... of 22` - the concatenation operator `+` does **not** add a space automatically {BTW `number1 + 1` will not *`increase a number by 2`* as described in comment}

Answer (score -1):

This one is funny one. You see when you put space the output is as you wish

```
This number is multiple of 2 2
This number is multiple of 2 3
This number is multiple of 2 4
```

But when you remove the space the answer is still coming right but it is getting joined with the number 2 in the statement i.e.

```
This number is multiple of 22 -- here 2 is from the statement and the next one is from answer
This number is multiple of 23 -- here 2 is from the statement and the next one is from answer
This number is multiple of 23 -- here 2 is from the statement and the next one is from answer
```